# HTTP authentication without Curl in PHP

Tags: php, security, curl, https, http-authentication

Right now I have a application in PHP, which works the HTTP authentication using curl. I believe, this the better authentication method to compare other authentication methods in-terms of security and code complexity.

But still I am wishing to know is there any other method available, better than curl.

Comment: file_get_contents using a context also works fine

Comment: exactly what does curl have to do with http authentication in your app? And in any case, you're asking for opinions, which are explicitly offtopic, and would be useless anyways, since you haven't provided nearly enough details to have a useful opinion in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

I personally prefer HTTP Basic Auth for my php applications. Check the below links for more detail

http://php.net/manual/en/features.http-auth.php
http://www.hackingwithphp.com/15/4/3/authentication-over-http
http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/webprog/pcook/ch08_10.htm
http://evertpot.com/223/